# Floating point exception error in simple c++ code

Tags: c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int t,x,y,z,set,i,check=0;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        cin>>x>>y>>z;
        
        check=z-(x+y);
       
      for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(check%i==0)
            {
                set=i;
            }
           // i++;
        }
        cout<<set<<endl;
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

While I run this code then I get run time error like

> FLoating point exception

and from next input it gives error like:

> dash: 2: 4:not found

Comment: It is in the `check%i` line when `i` is `0`. You have a division by zero exception I think.

Comment: Did you debug your code to see where the exception is being thrown?  If you did, then it should be obvious to you as to which line of code is the issue.   Just to warn you -- with a rep of 50, not debugging your own code is worthy of a downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a floating point exception because I divided i by 0 so I need to start loop from 1.